# How can we write to a Kafka topic and read from a kafka topic locally from IDE

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have created a kafka topic locally using terminal

`> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

Then I tried writing into this topic from intellij. My code takes the following arguments

`--group group-1 --topic test --brokers localhost:9092 --schemaRegistryUrl https://schema-registry.com`

But when I run my code with the specified brokers it says

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**

**Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.**

I am not sure if I'm following the right procedure to connect with localhost or writing to a topic from Ide. Any suggestions or links to navigate will be helpful.

Comment: Try assembling a jar and passing the same arguments, to see if it is related to the arguments/code rather than IDE setup

Comment: Please show your code. And based on the error, it seems Kafka may have crashed

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is no different than the terminal.

Please ensure Kafka process is still running

Comment: kafka process is running and now I get run errors something like this

 ```DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: EOF during handshake, handshake status is NEED_UNWRAP```

and also these

```[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.network.SslTransportLayer - [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7ff2b41b] Failed to send SSL Close message
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe```

Comment: 1) Make sure your client version matches your broker 2) If you have not modified any settings, you aren't using SSL